# Unique ID Generator (Google Forms/Google Sheets/Google Studio)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, looker-studio

I am currently working with health data and I wanted to create a visual on google studio that shows that amount of time a player missed due to each injury. However I am only able to show the total sum of the time missed due to an injury if a player suffered two of the same injuries. For example, a player suffered a knee injury in May that resulted in him missing 25 days. He then suffered another knee injury in July that resulted in him missing 15 days. The graph would show that he has missed 40 days due to a knee injury instead of Knee Injury 25 days, Knee Injury2 15 days. I believe the only way I can solve this issue is if I have a unique ID for each Injury. We currently update our google sheets through google forms. So I am wondering if there is a way to create an array formula of some sort that generate a unique ID when there is a value in the Injury column. If the Injury column is blank I want the ID column to be blank as well.

Any suggestions? I've looked into Google Script coding but having trouble with that.

Sorry for the lengthy post.

Thanks

-- Addition --

I am also hoping to have a bar graph show the data above. So for example I have the Player Name Column as a Dimension, the Injury Column as the Breakdown Dimension, and then some kind of calculated field that sums the Time Missed (Days) column by the Injury ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom formula like this:

```
function generate_ids(values) {
  values = values.map(row=>row[0])
  const ids = values.map(val=>[val?Utilities.getUuid():''])
  return ids
}
```

Use the formula in your sheet as:

```
=generate_ids(A2:A)
```

If injury data is stored in column A starting from row 2, or adapt the range reference according to your sheet setup.